# Mono fonts for all GtkTextView with CSS file with GTK+ 3.20

Tags: css, c, gtk, glade

I work on a project in C using GTK+.
This project is for GTK+3.6 minimum.

I would like to set all GTKTextView in monospace font. Before the last update of GTK to GTK3.20, my CSS sheet was working well with :

```
GtkTextView {
  font: Mono
}
```

Now, it is not working anymore. However, glade has a property :
    `<property name="monospace">True</property>`
but this property exists since GTK 3.16 and debian stable is on GTK3.14. Of course I want it portable.

My question is: how I can do it ? How I can set all my gtkTextView to the monospace font ?

Comment: That CSS is invalid. Try `font: monospace;` instead for the second line. Does it work now? You can also try changing the selector to `textview`. I'll have to look up what the `monospace` property does on GtkTextView. Is there a reason setting a text tag that sets the font isn't optimal?

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I wrote textview { font: monospace } and it works. Thank you so much, however I'm sorry I don't understand your last question.

Comment: It is working well on Linux, but not on OS-X

Comment: What happens on OS X?

Comment: Nothing. On linux my textview is in monospace. On OS X no. No errors returned by gtk_css_provider_load_from_path

Comment: That's very weird. Pango clearly checks for `monospace` on OS X and substitutes `"Courier"` (see `pango/pangocoretext-fontmap.c`)... What happens if you just specify `"Courier"`? Does it still not work?

Comment: No. It does not work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GTK 3.20 changed the way that CSS selectors work.

Pre-GTK 3.20, this was correct:

```
GtkTextView {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Starting with GTK 3.20, this is correct:

```
textview {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

If you're not sure about a particular platform, you can check with the GTK Inspector what selector is needed: run your app with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

It's worth noting that the pre-GTK 3.20 CSS selectors were experimental and not intended to be stable API.

If you have to support both forms, then your best bet is probably to make two stylesheets and load one or the other depending on the value of `GTK_MAJOR_VERSION` and `GTK_MINOR_VERSION`.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation. It does not work on OS-X but I understand why it was not working anymore on Linux. So now, on Linux it's ok.

Comment: Can you check with the inspector on OSX to see what's not working about the selector?

Comment: No that's ok now. I've re-installed Gtk and it's now working well !! Thank you for your precious help. Now I can use CSS sheet. My last question is to use CSS in C code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250497/change-text-color-for-gtktoggletoolbutton-in-c-code-gtk3/37253231#37253231

Comment: @ptomato would `GtkTextView, textview` not work with the GTK+ CSS engine?

Comment: Oh, that would work, but would be less explicit, and a pain to untangle when you need to stop supporting < 3.20 for other reasons...