# Change text color for GtkToggleToolButton in C code (GTK+3)

Tags: css, c, gtk

Recently I found the way to change color of GtkToggleToolButton text with a CSS sheet (Gtk 3.20):

```
#histoToolGreen label {
    color: green;
}

#histoToolBlue label {
    color: blue;
}
```

To do that, I changed the color of the label rather than that of the button. It works well. But now I want doing the same in C code. So I write :

```
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, "#histoToolRed label {color: red;}", -1, NULL);
gtk_style_context_add_provider(
            gtk_widget_get_style_context(lookup_widget("histoToolRed")),
            GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),
            GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

But that does not work. I also tried, with no success:

```
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, "* {color: red;}", -1, NULL);
```

and many other things.

Can someone tell me how to change color of GtkToggleToolButton text in C code using CSS provider ?

Answer (score 0):

I've made no progress trying to add CSS styling at the widget level. I've only managed to get it to work by adding a style sheet at the application level with [gtk_css_provider_get_default](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html#gtk-css-provider-get-default).

What I expected when I did something similar to what you've done is that the style would be applied to the widget I attached it to, and all of it's children. What I found is that style is only applied to the individual widget that got the provider added to it.